# Pass data from JQuery to database via Javascript/AJAX/JSON/PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, jquery

I am attempting to add data to my database from my HTML code via the use of JQuery, AJAX/JSON and PHP using an MVC model. Below is a small sample of what I am looking to achieve.

In my front end I have a checkbox with different options and a button named 'Add'. The selected elements from here are picked up by a Javascript function, which I have tested properly, once this is done I call another Javascript function to do the AJAX/JSON . What I am still fresh on is the actual AJAX/JSON process that sends the data to PHP.

My Javascript function:

```
function add_fruits(fruit_name, fruit_type){
    var success = "Fruit added";
    var error = "Fruit not added";

    var params = {
        'fruit_name' : fruit_name,
        'fruit_type' : fruit_type
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add_fruits.php",
        async: false,
        data: params,
              success: function(success){
                  alert(success);
              },
              error: function(error){
                  alert(error);
              }
    });
}
```

My PHP function:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-type: application/json');

require_once 'lib/connection_files.php';


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='POST')
{
    $fruit_name = no_sql_injection($_POST['fruit_name']);
    $fruit_type = no_sql_injection($_POST['fruit_type']);

    $fruits = new fruits();
    $result = $fruits->add_fruits($fruit_name, $fruit_type);
    $tmp = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($result == 1)
    {//RESULT must return 1 to verify successful insertion to database
        //send confirmation to front end
    }
    else
    {
        //send error message to front end
    }
}
else{
    //tell front end there was error sending data via AJAX
}
?>
```

Note that the add_fruits() function takes care of doing the Queries to the database, I did not include it here because it is irrelevant to my issue.

Comment: I think you need to send a string, I could be wrong but it seems like a good place to start debugging. Try stringifying the data before send. Then you need to parse the text in PHP to unstringify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `echo` in your PHP:

**PHP**

```
else {
    //send error message to front end
    echo "Error Adding Fruits";
}
```

**JS**

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data == "1") {
        //data added to db
    }
    else {
        alert(data);
    }
}
```